# net module in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make a server based on the net module. what I don't understand is on which event I'm supposed to put the response code: 
on(data,function()) could still be in the middle of receiving more data from the stream (so it might be to early to reply)
and on(end,function()) is after the connection is closed .

thank you for your help

Comment: Do you want to do raw TCP or HTTP?

Comment: TCP has no concept of a message, it models just a stream of bytes. You'll have to listen to `data` and detect your own message format in the stream.

Comment: But how can I detect it? for example, how is it detected for the http protocol?

Answer (score 2):

The socket event ('data'), calls the callback function every time an incoming data buffer is ready for reading,, and the event emits the socket buffer of data,,
so use this,,

```
socket.on('data',function(data){
    // Here is the function to detect the real data in stream
});
```

this can help for node v0.6.5, http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/net.html#event_data_

and this for clear understanding for the Readable streames,
         http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/streams.html#readable_Stream

Comment: thanks, but I still don't understand what will be the right way to detect the end of my message format

Comment: what's your message formate ?,, inside the callback function place the code require to detect the end of it,